# Creatively-formatted Resumes

Tags: resume, job-search, recruitment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add custom effects/formatting to my resume (to showcase my skills)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/add-custom-effects-formatting-to-my-resume-to-showcase-my-skills)

Every so often I hear suggestions like "print your resume on bright yellow paper to help it get noticed" (assuming you are giving someone hard copies of your resume).  Or, like in "Guerilla Marketing for Job Hunters [X].0", they suggest [putting quotes from your references and logos from previous employers on your resume](http://www.mscareergirl.com/2010/03/30/10-guerrilla-job-search-tactics-that-work/).  But every now and then hear just the opposite, that all these little gimmicks just annoy recruiters, and they'd rather just get a traditionally-formatted resume. So the question is ...

Do creatively-formatted resumes get noticed (in a good-way), or do they annoy recruiters?

Comment: Have you seen http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/add-custom-effects-formatting-to-my-resume-to-showcase-my-skills?

Answer (score 4):

For starters, resumes are rarely on paper anymore--at least not in the first couple of rounds. So, the first goal is that your resume is easily machine-readable.

Secondly, resumes are a very particular type of document for a very particular type of purpose. Gimmicks are likely more risky than effective in this situation.

Comment: +1 for For starters, resumes are rarely on paper anymore

Comment: how does this answer the question? This might be true but nothing you said addresses what the asker is looking for

Comment: It answers the question by pointing out the question is a) irrelevant due to the first point and b) a bad idea based on the second point.